# The name of the surface defined by the equation $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, terminology

For a homework, the teacher gave us the following surface with equation $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$ and he asked us for the name of it.

To be honest, I am really new in geometry-related stuff, so I am not really sure of the name of this surface.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric says Elliptic hyperboloid of one sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the traces in the coordinate planes, that is, where the surface intersects the planes. When $x=0,$ for example, we have $$y^2-z^2=1,$$ which is a unit rectangular hyperbola in the $yz$-plane.

When $y=0,$ you also have a similar hyperbola in the $xz$-plane.

Finally when $z=0,$ you have the equation $x^2+y^2=1,$ which is the unit circle in the $xy$-plane. It follows that all sections parallel to the trace in this plane are circles. Thus, this is a surface of revolution, whose traces are hyperbolae.

It is a just one connected piece and is one of the quadric surfaces (surfaces that are at most quadratic in their coordinates). This is a hyperboloid of one sheet. In particular, it is a hyperboloid of revolution. It belongs to the more general class known as elliptic hyperboloids of one sheet, where instead of circular sections as we have here, we have elliptic sections.